# How do I loop correctly?

Tags: r, loops

Here is the data below. I'm not sure which type of looping I should be using, but here is what I am looking to do: If, for row 1, there is a 6 present, then for column 7 we have "Yes", if there is no 6 present, then column 7 has "No". Ignore columns 8 & 9.

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
 [1,]    1    6    1    1    6    1   NA   NA   NA
 [2,]    5    5    5    5    5    5   NA   NA   NA
 [3,]    1    1    6    1    1    6   NA   NA   NA
 [4,]    5    5    5    5    5    5   NA   NA   NA
 [5,]    6    1    1    6    1    1   NA   NA   NA
 [6,]    5    5    5    5    5    5   NA   NA   NA
 [7,]    1    6    1    1    6    1   NA   NA   NA
 [8,]    5    5    5    5    5    5   NA   NA   NA
 [9,]    1    1    6    1    1    6   NA   NA   NA
[10,]    5    5    5    5    5    5   NA   NA   NA
```

Here is the code that I have.

```
data.matrix <- matrix(data=NA,nrow = b, ncol = n+3)
b <- 10
n <- 6
for (i in 1:b)
{
  data.matrix[,1:n] <- sample(6,n,replace=T)
}
```

Side Note: I keep getting this error
"the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"

Comment: Your data looks like a `matrix` of type `integer` (or `numeric`), so the moment you try to set column 7 to `"Yes"`, it will convert all of your numbers to strings. Is that what you intend? This might be better handled with a `data.frame` or an external vector to store your `"Yes"`/`"No"` values.

Comment: You might be able to start with something like: `ifelse(rowSums(m[,1:6] == 6L) > 0, "Yes", "No")` and store it somewhere else (not in this matrix).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using `apply`:

```
a[,7] <- apply(a, 1, function(x) ifelse(max(x,na.rm = T) == 6,"YES","NO"))
```

where `a` is the input data.frame/tibble. As commented above, if you have `matrix`, then convert it to `data.frame` and perform this operation.

Comment: `sample(6,n,replace=T)`, @r2evans

Comment: But ... the logic the OP was suggesting was equality, which (to me) might suggest a different view might look for a different number.

Comment: Well, the OP said "there is a 6 present", so if max is 6, then present, if max is not 6, then absent as it is sampled up to 6

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution with `lapply` and `which`:

```r
res <- apply(data.matrix, 1, function(x) {
  x[[7]] <- length(which(x == 6)) > 0
  x
})
res <- t(res)
```

Comment: Perhaps `any(x==6)` instead of `length(...)>0`?

Comment: I guess, that will be simpler